# Redirect in Safari as soon as you open iOS Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, ios13

I am developing a simple iOS app with Swift, I would need to know if there is a method to direct Safari to a URL as soon as the app opens, without button clicks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the ViewWillAppear methods you can open an URL calling this methods:

```
if let link = URL(string: "https://yoursite.com") {
  UIApplication.shared.open(link)
}
```